# How to get history of a git branch (Starting Point) once fast forward merge happens

Tags: git, version-control, github, merge, fast-forward

I have developing a program to query the history of a particular branch, whereby I would like to get the activities performed on that branch only:

1. Would like to display the comments made by the user on that branch.
2. Other information.

I can do this when my master branch and my feature branch (on which I would like to query) are yet not merged.

What I can do is that I can query between master and feature-branch like this and get the logs.

```
git log master..feature-branch.
```

I get the list of activities performed.

But My problem is that when Fast Forward Merge Happens in the Branch I am not able to query or get the data for that branch as the following command returns no rows.

```
git log master..feature-branch.
```

Nothing is returned.

I would like to know is there any way out in Git using commands to find out the history even though a fast forward merge happens.

Answer (score 1):

In git, branches don't maintain a distinct identity when they're merged into other branches, whether that branch is a fast-forward merged or not. Thus, depending on the command,

```
git log master..branch
```

to get a list of commits that are unique to `branch` is not going to be a reliable nor feasible method. Branches in git are just ephemeral and transitory references, they aren't actually permanently associated with commits.

The best you can do is to non-fast-forward merge branches, so that you can at least determine that a branch occurred. But unless you keep a branch reference or a tag at that merge commit, you have no way of using the `git log` command to "query" a branch name to find commits belonging to that branch.

**Also**, once a branch is merged into `master`, all of that branch's commits are then commits in `master` as well, so they no longer uniquely belong to that branch.

Comment: Ok so is there any way of knowing how many commits were made on that branch after it is fast-forward merged with master, in that way I can query the last N logs using git log branch -N and get all the operations performed on that branch ? My requirement is to get the activities which were performed on that branch, either using command or programatically.

Comment: If you fast-forward merge a branch into any other branch (such as `master`), then the two branches basically share the same commits. Again, commits don't know anything about branches. So if you use a fast-forward merge, there is no way that you can tell one branch apart from another, since they both will then share the exact same commits.